# ASP.NET 4 emitting HTML differently in IIS7 vs IIS6 - is there a fix?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, iis-7.5

A page in our application uses a GridView for displaying -- which gets emitted as a table.  We  prefer to leave off the borders, so these are coded to be suppressed.  See this code:

```
<asp:GridView CssClass="detail" AutoGenerateColumns="false" UseAccessibleHeader="true" RowStyle-CssClass="detail_data" BorderWidth="0" HeaderStyle-CssClass="detail_label" runat="server" ID="RiembursementRequestGrid">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderText="RR Id" DataField="RR ID" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Official Station" DataField="Official Station" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Official Residence" DataField="Official Residence" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Description" DataField="Description" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Routing Status" DataField="Routing Status" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderText="Amount Requested" DataField="Amount Requested" DataFormatString="{0:c}" HtmlEncode="false" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderText="Taxable Amount" DataField="Taxable Amount" DataFormatString="{0:c}" HtmlEncode="false" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderText="Travel Advance" DataField="Travel Advance" DataFormatString="{0:c}" HtmlEncode="false" />
    </Columns>              
</asp:GridView>
```

The relevant CSS class items are:

```
.detail
{
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Arial";
    empty-cells: show;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.detail_data
{
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: normal;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.detail_label
{
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

There is a difference between what's emitted by the workstation vs that emitted by the server.

On my dev workstation, which is Win7 running IIS7.5, the borders are properly absent.  On the Win2003 server, running IIS6, the borders are present.  This is with the exact same code and CSS, and the same browser viewing it.  Here's comparison screenshots:

[image: Screenshot comparison]

There is a difference in the code that's being emitted.  Here's the HTML code for the table opening tag on the workstation running IIS7.5 :

```
<table class="detail" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="0" id="RiembursementRequestGrid" style="border-width:0px;border-collapse:collapse;">
```

And on the server running IIS6

```
<table class="detail" cellspacing="0" rules="all" id="RiembursementRequestGrid" style="border-width:0px;border-collapse:collapse;">
```

As you can see, the only difference is that one tag omits **border="0"**.  And for that one the border is truly missing.  I would have thought that "border-width: 0" would have covered that particular base, however.

Note that besides the opening table tags all other emitted HTML (except viewstate value) is identical.

The questions are:

- Is this truly related to the differences between the IIS versions
- How would you approach fixing it?

Comment: did you test this on multiple browsers? sometimes i get weird border behavior while using firefox

Comment: Unfortunately, one of the controls in the application only works on IE, so our users cannot use FF or Chrome, etc.  FWIW this app is only used by our company's employees, so multiple-browser support was viewed as less important at the time it was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you experimented with the `controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion` setting in web.config?

If it's set to 3.5 or higher, border values will be omitted on `table`, `image`, and `imagebutton` tags.

Details here: http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes

Comment: That is an excellent suggestion!  It does indeed look like the answer to the problem.  It turns out that I'm not the only dev who has seen this problem in our organization -- I've passed this info along to the others.  I'll be doing some further checking on it.